# mlflow models serve -m mlflow_model

Tags: mlflow

I have a problem with serve MLflow. When I execute this code :

```
mlflow models serve -m mlflow_model/
```

I have this error:

```
2022/07/24 14:11:15 INFO mlflow.pyfunc.backend: === Running command 'source /opt/anaconda3/bin/../etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate mlflow-a116dac3ec81be8ec538fa60f4402b7d813c2192 1>&2 && exec gunicorn --timeout=60 -b 127.0.0.1:5000 -w 1 ${GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS} -- mlflow.pyfunc.scoring_server.wsgi:app'
[2022-07-24 14:11:16 +0200] [7534] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-07-24 14:11:16 +0200] [7534] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 5000)
[2022-07-24 14:11:16 +0200] [7534] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2022-07-24 14:11:17 +0200] [7534] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 5000)
[2022-07-24 14:11:17 +0200] [7534] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2022-07-24 14:11:18 +0200] [7534] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 5000)
[2022-07-24 14:11:18 +0200] [7534] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2022-07-24 14:11:19 +0200] [7534] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 5000)
[2022-07-24 14:11:19 +0200] [7534] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2022-07-24 14:11:20 +0200] [7534] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 5000)
[2022-07-24 14:11:20 +0200] [7534] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2022-07-24 14:11:21 +0200] [7534] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('127.0.0.1', 5000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/anaconda3/bin/mlflow", line 8, in <module>
  sys.exit(cli())
 File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
  return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
  rv = self.invoke(ctx)
 File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
  return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
 File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
  return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
 File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
  return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
 File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
  return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/models/cli.py", line 68, in serve
  return _get_flavor_backend(
 File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/backend.py", line 261, in serve
  raise Exception(
Exception: Command 'exec gunicorn --timeout=60 -b 127.0.0.1:5000 -w 1 ${GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS} -- mlflow.pyfunc.scoring_server.wsgi:app' returned non zero return code. Return code = 1
```

conda.yaml
channels:

- defaults
- anaconda
  dependencies:
- python=3.9.12
- pip<=22.1.2
- pip:

  - mlflow
  - cloudpickle==2.0.0
  - scikit-learn==1.0.2
    name: mlflow-env

I have changed the port to 8502 but in vain. I have this message:

```
[2022-07-26 02:28:06 +0200] [45925] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8502 (45925)
```

[2022-07-26 02:28:06 +0200] [45925] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-07-26 02:28:06 +0200] [45933] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 45933
/opt/anaconda3/envs/mlflow-278b1bb076f93c0a5f2665638173d22fba5482d5/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/**init**.py:40: UserWarning: Starting from version 2.2.1, the library file in distribution wheels for macOS is built by the Apple Clang (Xcode_8.3.3) compiler.
This means that in case of installing LightGBM from PyPI via the `pip install lightgbm` command, you don't need to install the gcc compiler anymore.
Instead of that, you need to install the OpenMP library, which is required for running LightGBM on the system with the Apple Clang compiler.
You can install the OpenMP library by the following command: `brew install libomp`.
warnings.warn("Starting from version 2.2.1, the library file in distribution wheels for macOS "

I show you too my ports already used:

COMMAND     PID             USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
loginwind   170 mohamedads    8u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4b08a76d93      0t0  UDP *:*
ControlCe   435 mohamedads   20u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4b08a6a8d3      0t0  UDP *:*
rapportd    480 mohamedads    3u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4b08a76773      0t0  UDP *:*
rapportd    480 mohamedads    4u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4b08a76a83      0t0  UDP *:*
rapportd    480 mohamedads    7u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4b08a78923      0t0  UDP *:*
identitys   485 mohamedads   26u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4b08a629d3      0t0  UDP *:*
identitys   485 mohamedads   28u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4b08a49c33      0t0  UDP *:*
sharingd    493 mohamedads    4u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4b08a42a83      0t0  UDP *:*
sharingd    493 mohamedads    8u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4b08a42463      0t0  UDP *:*
sharingd    493 mohamedads    9u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4b08a42153      0t0  UDP *:*
sharingd    493 mohamedads   10u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4b08a436c3      0t0  UDP *:*
sharingd    493 mohamedads   14u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4b08a76153      0t0  UDP *:*
sharingd    493 mohamedads   33u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4b08a6ca83      0t0  UDP *:*
sharingd    493 mohamedads   34u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4b08a6d0a3      0t0  UDP *:*
WiFiAgent   511 mohamedads    5u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4b08a6f8d3      0t0  UDP *:*
Dropbox     548 mohamedads   71u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd5823123      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:49185->162.125.6.20:https (ESTABLISHED)
Dropbox     548 mohamedads  107u  IPv6 0xd7d0f596050d7c3      0t0  TCP *:17500 (LISTEN)
Dropbox     548 mohamedads  108u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd4f8d67b      0t0  TCP *:17500 (LISTEN)
Dropbox     548 mohamedads  109u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4b08a75b33      0t0  UDP *:17500
Dropbox     548 mohamedads  147u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd4f8abcb      0t0  TCP localhost:17603 (LISTEN)
Dropbox     548 mohamedads  148u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd4f8ebcb      0t0  TCP localhost:17600 (LISTEN)
Dropbox     548 mohamedads  155u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd5825bcb      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:65500->162.125.19.9:https (ESTABLISHED)
Dropbox     548 mohamedads  167u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd582467b      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:65483->162.125.19.131:https (ESTABLISHED)
assistant   564 mohamedads   45u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4b08a74ef3      0t0  UDP *:*
com.apple   793 mohamedads   43u  IPv6 0xd7d0f596050bbc3      0t0  TCP localhost:65493->localhost:8501 (ESTABLISHED)
Notes      1226 mohamedads   13u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd582267b      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:65232->imap.1and1.fr:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Notes      1226 mohamedads   14u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd582267b      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:65232->imap.1and1.fr:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Notes      1226 mohamedads   37u  IPv6 0xd7d0f59605052c3      0t0  TCP [2a01:e34:ecb0:2610:e1d7:5d2e:8475:4d33]:65084->wo-in-x6d.1e100.net:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Notes      1226 mohamedads   38u  IPv6 0xd7d0f59605052c3      0t0  TCP [2a01:e34:ecb0:2610:e1d7:5d2e:8475:4d33]:65084->wo-in-x6d.1e100.net:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
python3.9  1314 mohamedads    5u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd5808bcb      0t0  TCP localhost:commplex-main (LISTEN)
Google    14186 mohamedads   20u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd5b41bcb      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:65486->192.168.0.17:8009 (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   24u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd582abcb      0t0  TCP localhost:65495->localhost:commplex-link (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   27u  IPv6 0xd7d0f59605060c3      0t0  TCP [2a01:e34:ecb0:2610:e1d7:5d2e:8475:4d33]:49156->[2606:4700::6812:1a91]:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   30u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd4f8967b      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:49159->249.195.120.34.bc.googleusercontent.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   31u  IPv6 0xd7d0f4b08a78c33      0t0  UDP [2a01:e34:ecb0:2610:e1d7:5d2e:8475:4d33]:55745->par21s22-in-x0a.1e100.net:https
Google    14186 mohamedads   33u  IPv6 0xd7d0f5960507cc3      0t0  TCP [2a01:e34:ecb0:2610:e1d7:5d2e:8475:4d33]:49158->par10s34-in-x0e.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   34u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd4f8e123      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:49155->249.195.120.34.bc.googleusercontent.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   35u  IPv6 0xd7d0f59605098c3      0t0  TCP [2a01:e34:ecb0:2610:e1d7:5d2e:8475:4d33]:65533->[2606:4700:4400::ac40:929e]:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   37u  IPv6 0xd7d0f596050adc3      0t0  TCP [2a01:e34:ecb0:2610:e1d7:5d2e:8475:4d33]:49154->par21s05-in-x01.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   38u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd581e67b      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:49182->server-52-84-174-19.cdg50.r.cloudfront.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   39u  IPv6 0xd7d0f5960506ec3      0t0  TCP [2a01:e34:ecb0:2610:e1d7:5d2e:8475:4d33]:65507->[2606:4700:20::681a:cf5]:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   40u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd583667b      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:65506->ec2-52-202-168-65.compute-1.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   41u  IPv6 0xd7d0f596050b4c3      0t0  TCP [2a01:e34:ecb0:2610:e1d7:5d2e:8475:4d33]:49161->[2600:9000:218d:a000:b:67f0:7600:93a1]:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   42u  IPv6 0xd7d0f5960508ac3      0t0  TCP [2a01:e34:ecb0:2610:e1d7:5d2e:8475:4d33]:49160->[2a04:4e42:1d::282]:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   44u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd580c123      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:65509->sledge-cdg.slb.sfdcsvc.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   45u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd580b67b      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:65508->sledge-cdg.slb.sfdcsvc.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   48u  IPv6 0xd7d0f596050e5c3      0t0  TCP [2a01:e34:ecb0:2610:e1d7:5d2e:8475:4d33]:65348->wo-in-f188.1e100.net:5228 (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   51u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd581dbcb      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:49183->server-52-84-174-118.cdg50.r.cloudfront.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   53u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd5825123      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:65510->sledge-cdg.slb.sfdcsvc.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   54u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd5b3cbcb      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:49173->par21s19-in-f2.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   55u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd5b41123      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:65511->sledge-cdg.slb.sfdcsvc.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   58u  IPv6 0xd7d0f596050ecc3      0t0  TCP [2a01:e34:ecb0:2610:e1d7:5d2e:8475:4d33]:49163->[2a04:4e42:1d::720]:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   59u  IPv6 0xd7d0f59605059c3      0t0  TCP [2a01:e34:ecb0:2610:e1d7:5d2e:8475:4d33]:65527->[2606:4700:4400::ac40:929e]:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   62u  IPv6 0xd7d0f5960511dc3      0t0  TCP [2a01:e34:ecb0:2610:e1d7:5d2e:8475:4d33]:49181->[2001:4860:4802:36::36]:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   63u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd583267b      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:49166->a104-124-109-108.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   65u  IPv6 0xd7d0f59605083c3      0t0  TCP [2a01:e34:ecb0:2610:e1d7:5d2e:8475:4d33]:65522->[2606:4700::6810:9440]:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   66u  IPv6 0xd7d0f59605091c3      0t0  TCP [2a01:e34:ecb0:2610:e1d7:5d2e:8475:4d33]:65525->[2606:4700::6810:9440]:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   68u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd582a123      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:65523->a23-220-25-199.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   71u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd5833bcb      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:49169->server-99-86-91-75.cdg50.r.cloudfront.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   72u  IPv6 0xd7d0f59605108c3      0t0  TCP [2a01:e34:ecb0:2610:e1d7:5d2e:8475:4d33]:49172->[2600:9000:218c:4200:1f:f723:6fc0:93a1]:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   73u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd5808123      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:65530->sledge-cdg.slb.sfdcsvc.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   74u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd580767b      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:65531->sledge-cdg.slb.sfdcsvc.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   75u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd5837bcb      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:49170->80.142.244.35.bc.googleusercontent.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   76u  IPv6 0xd7d0f59605067c3      0t0  TCP [2a01:e34:ecb0:2610:e1d7:5d2e:8475:4d33]:49167->[2a04:4e42:54::396]:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   77u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd5833123      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:49171->72.249.186.35.bc.googleusercontent.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   82u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd5b3b67b      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:49177->chi.outbrain.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
Google    14186 mohamedads   84u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd5831bcb      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:49178->chi.outbrain.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
Google    14186 mohamedads   85u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd5831123      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:49179->151.101.9.140:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   87u  IPv6 0xd7d0f5960512bc3      0t0  TCP [2a01:e34:ecb0:2610:e1d7:5d2e:8475:4d33]:49174->[2a04:4e42:1d::720]:https (ESTABLISHED)
Google    14186 mohamedads   93u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd581fbcb      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.14:49180->server-13-32-145-15.cdg50.r.cloudfront.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
pycharm   37549 mohamedads   10u  IPv6 0xd7d0f596050f3c3      0t0  TCP localhost:6942 (LISTEN)
pycharm   37549 mohamedads   46u  IPv6 0xd7d0f5960510fc3      0t0  TCP localhost:63342 (LISTEN)
python3.9 39875 mohamedads   19u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd5823bcb      0t0  TCP *:8501 (LISTEN)
python3.9 39875 mohamedads   20u  IPv6 0xd7d0f59605116c3      0t0  TCP *:8501 (LISTEN)
python3.9 39875 mohamedads   29u  IPv6 0xd7d0f596050c2c3      0t0  TCP localhost:8501->localhost:65493 (ESTABLISHED)
python3.9 43312 mohamedads    5u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd581c67b      0t0  TCP localhost:commplex-link (LISTEN)
python3.9 44086 mohamedads   10u  IPv4 0xd7d0f4fd581f123      0t0  TCP localhost:ddi-tcp-2 (LISTEN)
python3.9 44086 mohamedads   11u  IPv6 0xd7d0f59605101c3      0t0  TCP localhost:ddi-tcp-2 (LISTEN)

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

You can use `-p` option to change the port (default: `5000`) or you can use `-h` option to change the network address (default: `127.0.0.1`).
Something like this will do the job. (If you haven't already used port `5001`)

```
mlflow models serve -m mlflow_model/ -p 5001
```

#### Explanation

This is because your connection is in use as you can see on the errors.

```
[2022-07-24 14:11:16 +0200] [7534] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 5000)
```

I think your `5000` port is already in use by `mlflow ui` but I'm not sure. You can check port `5000` by running this command in linux `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`

Comment: Thanks so much. I have changed the port to 5001 but I have non access to the page : Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: I am on macOS last version. I use anconda terminal to executiong lines of commande. I don't have macOS terminal. Is it a problem?

Comment: I don't know much about macOS. Try changing host to `0.0.0.0`, maybe it would work. @MohamedADS

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried all solution but in vain.